# Range() including its bounds for positive and negative steps

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do a simple program that prints all the numbers in a range A to B, *including* B.

For ranges having bounds in increasing order, I know that I have to add 1 to the upper bound, like:

```
range(A, B+1)
```

But adding 1 to `B` won't work when the bounds are in decreasing order, like `range(17, 15, -1)`.

How can I code it to work for both increasing and decreasing ranges?

Comment: You could do something like `itertools.chain(range(A, B), [B])`, but then you'll lose the properties of having a range object…

Comment: I really don't see what you mean by 'the last number in the range won't be included' for negative values of 'the input' and how you have a different behavior compared to positive values. Please provide examples of what you expect and which cases gave you incorrect/unexpected results.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I mean, for example, what if the numbers are of a negative step as well. For example, range(17, 15, -1).

Comment: This is clearer now. I edited your question accordingly and added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't understand the question properly. There are 3 cases:

1. `A`, `B` both positive
2. `A` negative, `B` positive
3. `A`, `B` both negative

Now if I do this (in Python 2, to avoid having to do `list(range(...))`: this makes the explanation cleaner):

```
>>> A = 10; B = 20     # case 1
>>> range(A,B+1)
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
>>> A = -10; B = 2     # case 2
>>> range(A,B+1)
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
>>> A = -10; B = -2    # case 3
>>> range(A,B+1)
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2]
```

So your remark *the last number in the range won't be included* doesn't seem to fit with what I can see.

If you are receiving input data where `A > B`, then the problem is not the negative number, but the fact that `range()` expects the values to be in ascending order.

To cover that:

```
>>> A = 2; B = -2     # case 4
>>> A,B = sorted((A,B))
>>> range(A,B+1)
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

This also works for cases 1, 2, and 3.

If I have misunderstood the question please edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I see why you are facing this issue. Its because you are using the larger value as the first argument and smaller value at the second argument in the `range` (This is happening due to the negative sign).

For such cases following code will work  :

```
a = 5
b = -5
step = 1   
if b < 0:
    step = -1
range (a, b + step, step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works. Thank you.

```
if A>B and A < 0 and B < 0:
    print(list(range(A,B,-1)))
elif A<B:
    print(list(range(A,B)))
else:
    print(list(range(A,B,-1)))
```

Comment: The first case and the last case are the same, which suggests you can simplify that code to one `if..else`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that turns a normal range into one that includes both bounds, like:

```
def inclusive(r):
    return range(r.start, r.stop + r.step, r.step)
```

You should pass it a range, and it will return a range:

```
increasing_range = range(2, 5)
print(list(inclusive(increasing_range)))
# [2, 3, 4, 5]

decreasing_range = range(5, -5, -1)
print(list(inclusive(decreasing_range)))
# [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

even = range(2, 10, 2)
print(list(inclusive(even)))
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

for odd in inclusive(range(1, 5)):
    print(odd)
# 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Last number is never included in python range. You need to adjust the code accordingly.
e.g. 
To print values form -5 to -1(included) use,

```
>>> print(list(range(-5, 0)))
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

In reverse order

```
>>> print(list(range(-1, -6, -1)))
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```